# ng command is working in vs code PowerShell not in vs code git bash

Tags: angular, bash, visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-code

angular CLI commands are not working in vs code git bash whereas it's working in Powershell.
the error is as follows:-
C:\Users\amitk\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found

Answer (score 2):

I know it's little bit late, but maybe it'll help some other folks.

You have to set `alias ng` in git bash, after that it will work.

First localize `ng.cmd` file in `C:/Users/Username/AppData/Roaming/npm/ng.cmd`
Go to your git bash and type in:

```bash
alias ng='C:/Users/Username/AppData/Roaming/npm/ng.cmd'
```

After that it will recognize your command.

To set `alias ng` permanently in git bash, you have to edit the `aliases.sh` file in `C:/Program Files/Git/etc/profile.d/aliases.sh`.

Just add the alias syntax to the other ones.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the value of the path variable in your environment variable. looks like it can't find the node command from the path in your git bash environment. Sometime in your windows, the node was pointed to the windows node folder.

In the Powershell please run the command below to identify which node location it's using
`where node`

In your git bash check whether the path contains the directory which contains node command.

Comment: To locate a command in PowerShell, use [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command). Alternatively, use `where.exe`, but you must invoke it _with `.exe`_, because `where` is a built-in PowerShell alias for the unrelated [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) cmdlet.